# Send cron mails to root bundled every hour

Tags: logs, cron

Sometimes when there's a problem on my server, I get hundreds of emails in my root account which are caused by cron.

I want to be notified about those problems but isn't there a way to bundle those mails and send them once an hour?

Optimal would be if mail-subjects were analyzed and watched for new subjects within a timeframe of a day and **send mails with a new subject that day directly**, but following mails with a new subject bundled once an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure about bundling the emails but i know you could change youre cronjobs with crontab -e there you could for example `cat email1 | for file in /email/dir/; do cat $file >> email1` Here you append all youre emails to one big email so you will only have one file. Hope this works for you